# How to modify this JQuery CSS into my view?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am working on a web application that use **JQuery Mobile**. In this web application I have a view that show an input form mask. Something like this:

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="Title">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" id="Title" name="Title" style="margin-bottom:15px;" value="@Model.Title" />

    <label for="BugTraqID">BugTraqID:</label>
    <input type="number" id="BugTraqID" name="Title" min="0" step="1" style="margin-bottom:15px;" value="@Model.BugTraqID" />

    <label for="StatusID">StatusID:</label>
    <input type="number" id="StatusID" name="Title" min="0" max="10" step="0.1" style="margin-bottom:15px;" value="@Model.StatusID" />

    .....................................................................................
    .....................................................................................
    .....................................................................................
</div>
```

In this way there is no space between between an input tag and the next one. So I tryed to add a margin-bottom to all the input tag, something like this:

.ui-field-contain input {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

But doing in this way I obtain no result and I still have no margin.

Using FireBug on the previous page I obtain the following code:

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="Title">Title:</label>
    <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
        <input id="Title" type="text" value="Microsoft Internet Explorer CVE-2014-0310 Memory Corruption Vulnerability -TEST" style="margin-bottom:15px;" name="Title">
    </div>

    <label for="BugTraqID">BugTraqID:</label>
    <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
        <input id="BugTraqID" type="number" value="67299" style="margin-bottom:15px;" step="1" min="0" name="Title">
</div>
```

So, as you can see, the rendered version is pretty different from my original code because there is the external div having class **ui-field-contain** that contains another div having class **ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset** that finally contain my input tag.

So I have the following 2 doubts:

1) Why the rendered version is different from my code? Why the input tags are contained into the div having class **ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset**

2) I tryed to use the following CSS settings to obtain the margin between my inputs tag but it still not work:

```
<style>
    .ui-field-contain .ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset input {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
</style>
```

I also tryed with:

```
<style>
    .ui-field-contain .ui-input-text input{
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
</style>
```

but still have the same problem

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery Mobile you should put each label/input pair in its own fieldcontain:

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="Title">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" id="Title" name="Title" value="@Model.Title" />
</div>
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="BugTraqID">BugTraqID:</label>
    <input type="number" id="BugTraqID" name="Title" min="0" step="1" value="@Model.BugTraqID" />
</div>
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="StatusID">StatusID:</label>
    <input type="number" id="StatusID" name="Title" min="0" max="10" step="0.1" value="@Model.StatusID" />
</div>
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/48qrs/)**

This gives you a default spacing. If you want to tweak the spacing, you can target the CSS of the field contain DIV and leave the inputs/labels alone.

The reason your markup looks different in Firebug is because that's how jQM works. jQM takes basic markup and "enhances" it by applying its CSS and adding DOM elements as needed to get the mobile look and feel.

As an option, you can build a form inside a listview with each line in its own listitem. See the jQM demos for listview in the section titled Forms: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/listview/#Forms

Comment: Tnx so much, perfect explaination